# GAE JDO 3.01 datanucleus 3.1.3 Error:org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1945)

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I'm getting an error that happens only intermittently. The problem happens when

Here is my setup:
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3, 
datanucleus-core-3.1.3 
jdo-api-3.0.1. So I'm using JDO 3.0.1

I try and get a object from the space:

```
public  DAOCompany getCompany(DAOCompany company) {
        logger.debug("getCompany(): starting");
        DAOCompany comnpanyInDatabase = new DAOCompany();
        comnpanyInDatabase.setParsingSuccessfull(false);
        pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            comnpanyInDatabase = pm.getObjectById(DAOCompany.class, company.getKey());
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
        return comnpanyInDatabase;

    }
```

An exception happens when I try and replace the null dates on that object:

```
1:1425452404.383000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,382 DEBUG Request 9D596201 class:getCompany:1412 - getCompany(): starting
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.384000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,383 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Cache:debug:58 - Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.385000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,384 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@14f6866" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@5f7d5" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@4f1ffc"
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.385000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,385 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Cache:debug:58 - Object with id "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 0]
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.386000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,385 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Cache:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]")
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.388000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,386 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") is having the value in field "lastDownloaded_Image" replaced by a SCO wrapper
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.390000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,388 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") is having the value in field "lastDownloaded_JobEnhancedEvent" replaced by a SCO wrapper
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.392000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,390 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") is having the value in field "lastDownloaded_JobEvent" replaced by a SCO wrapper
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.394000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,392 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") is having the value in field "lastModified" replaced by a SCO wrapper
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.476000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,394 DEBUG Request 9D596201 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany@289c27" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOCompany:5921973989277696") is having the value in field "licenceExpiry" replaced by a SCO wrapper
    :  
    : 
    1:1425452404.478000 [s~test-server/17.382534582764030825].<stdout>: 07:00:04,478 ERROR Request 9D596201 class:isReceivedSessionValid:1490 - isReceivedSessionValid(): Error:org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1945)
    : org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
    : org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForCachedPC(JDOStateManager.java:562)
    : org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newForCachedPC(StateManagerFactory.java:254)
    : org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactory.newForCachedPC(ObjectProviderFactory.java:196)
    : org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getObjectFromLevel2Cache(ObjectManagerImpl.java:5095)
    : org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getObjectFromCache(ObjectManagerImpl.java:5034)
    : org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3286)
    : org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1722)
    : org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1740)
    : com.eurekaapp.server.dao.GoogleCloud.getCompany(GoogleCloud.java:1417)
    : com.eurekaapp.server.dao.GoogleCloud.isReceivedSessionValid(GoogleCloud.java:1462)
    : com.eurekaapp.server.service.DAOServiceImpl.isReceivedSessionValid(DAOServiceImpl.java:157)
    : com.eurekaapp.server.api.provider.admin.GetAllJobEventEnhancedJobCompleted.doPost(GetAllJobEventEnhancedJobCompleted.java:44)
    : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    : com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    : com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    : com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    : org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    : com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    : com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    : com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    : com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    : com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    : com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    : com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    :
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and using which version of the different software?

Comment: Hi Neil, sorry, it's JDO 2.3. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: so bearing in mind this is positively ANCIENT code being used and that code will not be getting an update, you seem to have two options. 1). upgrade to later software or 2). disable the L2 caching (the only thing I recognize in the stack trace). Maybe there was some problem in L2 caching years ago and was fixed since; I use L2 caching with DataNucleus (but not GAE) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Actually Neil.. I'm sorry but I confused my versions of datanucleus with JDO. It's actually datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3,  datanucleus-core-3.1.3 and jdo-api-3.0.1. So I'm using JDO 3.0.1.. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This page https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility  says what versions are available i.e there is a version that uses DataNucleus 3.2.x/3.3.x but you have to build it yourself. Other than that you follow option 2). in the earlier comment